# Como hacer que la variable de un loop sea parte del nombre de una variable

Tags: r

En R quiero crear un loop que genere columnas donde la variable que tome los distintos valores sea parte del nombre, acá va un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr:

DataFrame Inicial:

```
Firma      v_0  v_600  v_1200 v_1800 v_2400
1 Firma 1   0   100    700   1300   1900
2 Firma 2   0   200    800   1400   2000
3 Firma 3   0   300    900   1500   2100
4 Firma 4   0   400   1000   1600   2200
5 Firma 5   0   500   1100   1700   2300
6 Firma 6   0   600   1200   1800   2400
```

Dataframe Ideal:

```
 Firma     v_0 v_600 v_1200 v_1800 v_2400 v_600_0    v_1200_600   v_1800_1200   v_2400_1800
1 Firma 1   0   100    700   1300   1900       100         600        600         600
2 Firma 2   0   200    800   1400   2000       200         600        600         600
3 Firma 3   0   300    900   1500   2100       300         600        600         600
4 Firma 4   0   400   1000   1600   2200       400         600        600         600
5 Firma 5   0   500   1100   1700   2300       500         600        600         600
6 Firma 6   0   600   1200   1800   2400       600         600        600         600
```

Al final las columnas nuevas que son v_600_0, v_1200_600, v_1800_1200, v_2400_1800 son la resta entre las variables v_600 - v_0 = v_600_0, v_1200 - v_600 = v_1200_600.

El problema es que intente hacer un loop de la siguiente forma:

```
for ( i in seq(600,2400,600)){
  
 df$v_i_(i-600) = df$v_i - df$v_(i-600)
 
}
```

Pero el 'i' me lo toma como un string al utilizarlo en el nombre de la variable (es decir, df$v_i_(i-600) me lo toma como i y no por ej el primer valor del loop que es 600.

La idea es minimizar el número de líneas en el código y hacerlo en un loop y no manualmente crear cada columna.

Answer (score 0):

El bucle tiene varios problemas, menciono solamente el que te está produciendo el error: estás mezclando la indización por número/ubicación con la indización por nombre.

La primera acepta enteros para hacer subconjuntos, la segunda acepta nombres expresados como cadenas de caracteres. En tu caso podrías tratar de componer los nombres a partir de números usando `paste()` y `as.character()`, pero en ese caso se te podría complicar el operador `$` que solo acepta nombres, ni números ni cadenas.

Viendo el ejemplo de datos y del resultado esperado van tres posibles soluciones al problema. En los tres casos asumo que estás tratando de restar a cada columna la columna inmediatamente a la izquierda (anterior) y adosar las columnas con esas diferencias al final del data.frame usando como nombres una combinación de los nombres de ambas columnas. De hecho los nombres son el principal problema.

Primero los datos que estoy usando.

```
read.table(text =   
"Firma      v_0  v_600  v_1200 v_1800 v_2400
Firma1   0   100    700   1300   1900
Firma2   0   200    800   1400   2000
Firma3   0   300    900   1500   2100
Firma4   0   400   1000   1600   2200
Firma5   0   500   1100   1700   2300
Firma6   0   600   1200   1800   2400", header = T) -> foo
```

## Retrasando una matriz

Si lo vas a reutilizar muchas veces y quieres escribir poco código puede ser buena idea definir una función. En este caso `restar_anterior()` toma un data.frame como del ejemplo y regresa un data.frame con las columnas de diferencia al final.

```
restar_anterior <- function(x) {
  matriz = as.matrix(x[, -1])
  restada = matriz[,-1] - matriz[,-ncol(matriz)] 
  colnames(restada) = paste(colnames(matriz[,-1]), 
                            colnames(matriz[,-ncol(matriz)]), 
                            sep = "_")
  rownames(restada) = NULL
  cbind(foo, as.data.frame(restada))
}
restar_anterior(foo)
```

## Pivoteando los datos

Una alternativa es evitar los bucles y matrices y resolver el problema transformando los datos a formato largo (pares de clave-valor) y usando `lag()` para que la columna anterior pase a ser la fila anterior en un data.frame largo. Luego hacer la operación sobre columnas largas y lo regresar a formato ancho. Soluciona de manera relativamente elegante el problema de los nombres. Es complicada, pero se puede validar paso a paso.

```
foo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = v_0:v_2400) %>%  #Paso las columnas a formato largo, Firma permanece como id
  group_by(Firma) %>%                  #Agrupo por firma, mantengo el orden que tendría por fila
  mutate(out = value - lag(value),     #el que estaba a la izquierda en foo ahora está en la fila anterior poruqe lag()
         name_out = lag(name))  %>%    #Para componer los nombres despues
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Firma,         #Voy a perder datos, pero los reúno al final
              names_from = c(name, name_out),   #Por defecto los une con _
              values_from = c(out)) %>%         #Podría tb poner value, pero se me complican los nombres    
  select(where(~all(!is.na(.)))) %>%            #La primera columna no tenía info a la izquierda y se producen NA. Creo que esto es más seguro que un drop_na que se llevaría potencial NA reales de los datos
  left_join(foo, .)                             #El punto después por el orden de columnas
```

## Con un bucle dentro de una función

Aquí armo un bucle para hacer la resta entre cada columna y la anterior. Al bucle lo ubico dentro de una función para reducir el contacto con el entorno global. Al estar contenido en la función es menos probable que se confunda con nombres que están en el entorno o que haga un enchastre de objetos intermedios.

```
restar_columna_anterior <- function(x) {
  df <- x[ , -1]  #Asumo que la primera columna es la clave, la quito para facilitar las operaciones entre números
  out <- list()   #Creo una lista vacía en la que iré ubicando el output
  for (i in seq_along(df)) {      #El índice será numérico
    restado <- df[, i] - df[i-1]  #Esta es la parte fácil
  out[i] <- restado               #En cada ciclo se agrega un elemento a la lista
  }
  out[sapply(out, is.null)] <- NULL  #Tengo un NULL porque hay una columna sobre la que no se puede hacer la resta
  names(out) <- paste(names(df)[-1], names(df)[-length(names(df))], sep = "_")  #Armo los nombres
  cbind(x, as.data.frame(out))           #Coerciono out a data.frame (era una lista) y le pego los datos originales
}

resta_columna_anterior(foo)   #Uso la función
```